# How was the first async method created?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

In C#, the *async* keyword means that the method contains *await* keywords that call *async methods,* otherwise it won't be async. And, *await keyword* can be used only to *async methods.* So, the question is: how was the first async method created? Can I do this by myself? Or in order to make my method async I must use existing async methods?

Comment: you're mistaken about a number of concepts.  Please read this great article: it might help clarify a few things for you: [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: See duplicates for the long version. Short version is, the thing you can await does _not_ need to be a method marked `async`. It just has to support a mechanism called an "awaiter", with a method called `GetAwaiter()`. By far the most common example of this is the `Task` object. So anything that returns a `Task` object can be awaited, whether or not it's actually marked with `async`.

Comment: Jon Skeet also wrote a fabulous series of articles introducing us to the async/await world, when it first was introduced. You can learn an enormous amount about its underlying implementation details by reading the articles. Start here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/10/29/initial-thoughts-on-c-5-s-async-support/

Comment: @Peter Duniho: you're correct.  Thank you for giving the OP a bit of explanation :)  I'd also highly recommend the OP read this Microsoft article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/